# Difference between 'happened to be' and 'happens to have been'

Tags: infinitives

What's the difference?

> He happened to be at that wedding.
>
> He happens to have been at that wedding.

I know that different forms of the infinitive are used, but what's the difference in meaning?

Answer (score 3):

The difference here is the same difference as normal between *simple past* and *present perfect*.

(This structure isn't technically present perfect as "happen to" is never used in true present perfect: "<del>He has happened to be at the wedding</del>". But it is functionally equivalent to present perfect)

The simple past here, as usual, simply relates something that happened in the past.

The present perfect, as usual, relates something that happened or started in the past, and *has some connection to the present* -- hence *present* perfect.

So to this example, while both include the meaning that he was at the wedding by happenstance, the present perfect also includes the nuance that this fact has some connection to the present. For instance, if the speaker got a job offer from him because they happened to see him at that wedding, the speaker is focused on the present result of a past event, which is textbook present perfect.

Comment: Thank you, but what you call the present perfect is not a tense it's an infinitive. It's the perfect infinitive.

Comment: @user1425 You're right, it's not technically the standard present perfect structure, but in all other ways it is present perfect. I've improved the second paragraph to make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic construction *X **happens** [to verb]* essentially means *X [**verbs**]* - with the implication that speaker is saying something relatively unlikely that the audience didn't expect *(X might **not** [verb])*.

The difference between OP's examples is simply a matter of ***when*** something "unexpected / unplanned" either *took place* OR *became known*....

> 1: *John happened to be there*
> ... implies that *at the time of the wedding* it ***was*** "unplanned" / relatively unexpected that he ***would be*** there.

> 2: *John happens to have been there*
> ... implies that *at time of speaking* it ***is*** "unknown" / relatively unexpected that people should learn that he ***was*** there.

---

Note that the *second* version should only be used with caution. The implication is often that speaker is *disagreeing / arguing* with someone. Specifically, *someone who isn't aware* that John was at the wedding, and who is basing *false beliefs* on the assumption that John *wasn't* there. For example...

> A - "My brother John isn't much of a family man. As I expected, he didn't go to our cousin's wedding last week"
> B - "He happens to have been there. You just didn't see him because you spent all your time outside the reception hall smoking cigarettes!"

---

This comment from @PRL75 explains better than me exactly why OP's second version in particular should be used with caution (where the "surprise" relates to *speaker disabusing addressee's misconceptions* rather than the event itself having been unexpected in the past.

> It is (almost?) invariably used to inform someone of something they were unaware of, and would influence their opinion. e.g....
> "Why on earth would you think he could repair your TV?"
> "He happens to be a very competent electrician"

Comment: I think you've explained it much better than I did. I was trying to get across the idea that you express more eloquently , starting "Note that the second ...".

Comment: ty - but because I have enough rep to see "deleted" answers, I should point out that *you* explained that "reason for exercising caution" better than *me* in a comment. I trust you won't mind me including part of your comment in my answer text (comments are potentially ephemeral, and it's a point well worth making).